# I have OpenCV installed but I can't import and print cv2 version

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, conda, face-recognition

I have already installed OpenCV and it's located in users\danie\appdata\local\program\python\python39\lib\site-packages and this is the version [Version of opencv installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaoLd.png)

I have Python 3.9.10 installed
and conda version 4.12.0

When I run this code

```
`import cv2`
```

in Jupyter notebook, it will say

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13728/571303353.py in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

and when I run

```
print(cv2.__version__)
```

it just returns this:

```
      NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13728/309056062.py in <module>
    ----> 1 print(cv2.__version__)

NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
```

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: step1 -->Delete all your existing opencv installation and step 2 -->`python -m pip install opencv-python`

Comment: I've tried that also, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: use this `python -m pip install –upgrade pip`.  and `python -m pip install opencv-python` then Run `pip show opencv_python` in vscode integrated terminal to check if it's installed in current used environment. If it is, add the import sentence.

Comment: it works now, but i dont know which tutorial worked because I followed lots of tutorials and almost gave up. until I restarted Jupyter Notebook and ran the same code and it worked... the last tutorial I followed was this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fcc_jemaoNU&t=0s